# Assign multiple variables (x, y, z) to a 2D array

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab

I have a function with signature

```
function [A] = code(x,y,z);
```

I also have an excel spreadsheet. It is basically a 1024×1024 array which I have extracted from a 3D AFM image, 1024 is the number of pixel and the numbers in the array are the height of the surface.

How do I assign `x` to the column, `y` to the rows and `z` to the numbers inside the 2D array?

Comment: What sizes are you expecting inside the function named `code` for x, y and z?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. What are `x`, `y` and `z`? What are their sizes?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Basically I am trying to calculate the curvatures of 3D AFM images. X, Y, Z are the individual points on the surface for each pixel. In order to find the curvature, I need to find the gradient of X, Y and Z, so I need to assign X, Y, Z to the 2D excel array.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood, this could be it -

```
z = xlsread(FILE);
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(z,1),1:size(z,2));
out = code(x',y',z);
```